# SQL Stuff XML, GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the below query which returns these results via SQL's XML function:

[image]

It's successfully grouping by PO number, but I'm trying to get the XML list to also group by carrier...

So the row with carrier fedex would display just 123456 for alltrackingno, and the row with carrier ups would display ups987653 for alltrackingno.

Have tried all kinds of variations of join with no success.

Thank you in advance!

```
select ponumber,
       case
            when ca_type = 'FEX'
            then 'fedex'
            when ca_type = 'UPS'
            then 'ups' else ''
            end as carrier,
       stuff((select ', ' + ltrim(rtrim(trackingno)) from box ee
       where ltrim(rtrim(trackingno)) <> '' and ee.orderno=e.orderno
       order by box for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') as alltrackingno
       from box e right join carrier on e.shiplist =  carrier.ca_code
       right join cms on e.orderno = cms.orderno
       where cms.custnum = 100 and ltrim(rtrim(trackingno)) <> ''
       and emailedtracking = 0
       group by e.orderno, ponumber, ca_type
```

Comment: Just add `and ee.ca_type = e.ca_type` to the `STUFF`?

Comment: @ZLK, it doesn't work because ca_type is joined from the carrier table... I just can't seem to figure out the joins. This XML function is not one I use often.

Comment: Then you would need to do the same sort of join in your stuff.